# What are the best prettyprint options for C++ code?

Tags: c++, code-formatting, pretty-print

My partner and I are working on a prettyprinter for C++ code.  The tool parses input C++ code and prints the resulting AST, so we have quite a bit of flexibility.  We've implemented a few options for the user to control the output and now we're looking for opinions about the most important options.  If you could take a look at our current (below) and then tell us what you like/dislike, what else should be there, etc. that would be great.

Thanks,
Joe

Below are some of the current options (sorry for the length):

---

## 1.  Control Blocks

---

### 1.1 IndentString

---

Define the white space string that’s used for each indent.

Example:

•   IndentString “  ”

```
void f ()
{
  int a;
}
```

•   IndentString “\t”

```
void f ()
{
    int m;
}
```

---

### 1.2 OpenBraceLocation

---

Three options are: “EndOfLine”, “NextLine”, or “NextLineAsWellAsCloseParen”

Start the open braces on the same or next line as the keyword that it’s associated with.  Last option moves the close paren prior to the open brace if it exists to the next line as well.

Applies to if, while, for, switch and do-while statements.

If not present the “EndOfLine” option is used.

Example:

•   OpenBraceLocation EndOfLine

```
if(val){
    val++;
}
```

•   OpenBraceLocation NextLine

```
if(val)
{
    val++;
}
```

•   OpenBraceLocation NextLineAsWellAsCloseParen

```
if(val
){
    val++;
}
```

---

### 1.3 NoBracesAroundSingleStatementBlock

---

Braces are removed from statement blocks that have only one statement.  This option applies to do-while, for, if, and while blocks.

Example:

•   NoBracesAroundSingleStatementBlock is present

```
if(a)
    func();
```

•   NoBracesAroundSingleStatementBlock is not present

```
if(a)
{
    func();
}
```

---

## 2.  Classes

---

### 2.1 virtualQualifier

---

The options are:  “Everywhere” or “Minimalist”.  When “Everywhere” is used the keyword “virtual” appears in all derived classes in front of the function declared to be virtual in the base class.  With “Minimalist” it only appears in the base class.

Example :

•   virtualQualifier Everwhere

```
class Base
{
    virtual void f(int a);
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void f( int a);

class MostDerived : public Derived
{
    virtual void f( int a);
```

•   virtualQualifier Minimalist

```
class Base
{
    virtual void f(int a);
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    void f( int a);

class MostDerived : public Derived
{
    void f( int a);
```

---

### 2.2 SortClassMembers

---

The level options are “Access”, “Data/Functions” or “Functions/Data”, and “Alpha”.  If no level-option is provided or the SortClassMember is not present the order of the members is unchanged.

Example:

•   SortClassMembers Data/Functions Access Alpha

```
class Compiler 
{
private:
    string inputFileName;
public:
    Compiler( string const & inputFileName_);
    genOutput( string const & outputFileName_);
private:
    analyze();
    emitCode( string const & );
    parse();
    tokenize( string const & inputFileName_);
}
```

•   SortClassMembers Access Functions/Data Alpha

```
class C
{
public:
    Compiler( string const & inputFileName_);
    genOutput( string const & outputFileName_);
private:
    analyze();
    emitCode( string const & );
    parse();
    tokenize( string const & inputFileName_);
private:
    string inputFileName;
}
```

•   SortClassMembers Access Alpha

```
class C
{
public:
    Compiler( string const & inputFileName_);
    genOutput( string const & outputFileName_);
private:
    analyze();
    emitCode( string const & );
    string inputFileName;
    parse();
    tokenize( string const & inputFileName_);
}
```

---

## 3.  Files

---

### 3.1 MaxLineWidth

---

Define the maximum line width.  PrettyC++ will intelligently wrap longer lines if possible.

Example:

•   MaxLineWidth 80

```
int x = 123456789;
```

•   MaxLineWidth 10

```
int x =
123456789;
```

---

### 3.2 constLocation

---

The options are “Before” or “After”.  The Before option places the const keyword before the type specifier.  The After option places the const keyword after the type specifier.

Example :

•   constLocation Before

```
const int x;
```

•   constLocation After

```
int const x;
```

---

## 4.  Names

---

### 4.1 AllNamesStartCase

---

Options are “LowerCase” or “UpperCase”.

Example:

•   AllNamesStartCase LowerCase

```
int variable = 123456789;
```

•   AllNamesStartCase UpperCase

```
int Variable = 123456789;
```

---

### 4.2 AllNamesDelimitWords

---

Options are “CaseDelimited” or “UnderscoreDelimited”.  Words are identified by as either starting with a capital letter or following an underscore.

Example:

•   AllNamesDelimitWords CaseDelimited

```
int myVariable = 123456789;
```

•   AllNamesDelimitWords UnderscoreDelimited

```
int my_variable = 123456789;
```

---

### 4.3 FunctionNamesStartCase

---

Options are “LowerCase” or “UpperCase”.

Example:

•   FunctionNamesStartCase LowerCase

```
void function() { return; }
```

•   FunctionNamesStartCase UpperCase

```
void Function() { return; }
```

---

### 4.4 FunctionNamesDelimitWords

---

Options are “CaseDelimited” or “UnderscoreDelimited”.  Words are identified by as either starting with a capital letter or following an underscore.

Example:

•   FunctionNamesDelimitWords CaseDelimited

```
void myFunction() { return; }
```

•   FunctionNamesDelimitWords UnderscoreDelimited

```
void my_function() { return; }
```

Comment: "SortClassMembers", though nice, may cause different behavior in C++ (initialization order of member variables is in declaration order)

Comment: This is essentially an opinion poll, which belongs in the authors' development website. And the 'question' lists half their manual.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I miss in code formatters is something that gives me more hints about the structure of the code.  I often find myself indenting consecutive lines of almost-equal statements to highlight their correspondances and differences, much like this:

```
auto_ptr<Base::Int> x1 = get<DataModelI::Base::Int>( context, c_Input1 );
auto_ptr<Base::Real> x2 = get<DataModelI::Base::Real>( context, c_Input2 );
auto_ptr<Composite::Array> x3 = get<Composite::Array>( context, c_Input3 );
auto_ptr<Base::Real> x4 = get<DataModelI::Base::Real>( context, c_Input4 );
```

into that

```
auto_ptr<Base::Int       > x1 = get<DataModelI::Base::Int >( context, c_Input1 );
auto_ptr<Base::Real      > x2 = get<DataModelI::Base::Real>( context, c_Input2 );
auto_ptr<Composite::Array> x3 = get<Composite::Array      >( context, c_Input3 );
auto_ptr<Base::Real      > x4 = get<DataModelI::Base::Real>( context, c_Input4 );
```

This is totally unmaintainable: when another, longer, line is added, I lose time indenting all previous lines.  And yes, I did read Code Complete and partially agree with their statement about this :)

If you can add this (quite human, and subjective) aesthetic heuristic to a viewer, I would be pleased to hear from it.

I want my code as clear as possible.  In my dream code viewer, I can toggle viewing `using` declarations - maybe I don't even need them: I can toggle full-namespace viewing, can hide local variable declarations to just focus on the control flow, ...

Comment: Ohhhh the dream code viewer .... I've had many a dreams. :-)  Thanks for the suggestion.  Let me think about how to implement this and get back to you.

Comment: Can't be _that_ hard, really :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at eclipses code formatter.  It may be for Java, but it still has a lot of options that would apply to C++.  Otherwise, what you currently have looks good to me, but maybe a bit sparse...  I would elaborate a bit more, but I don't have the time right now, and I'm sure someone else will answer as well...

Also, Eclipse does have support for C++, but I've never looked at it before, but I'd assume it would have a code formatter as well.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) is an auto-indent program designed for C or C++. You can take a look at the options or the source if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Vera++](http://www.inspirel.com/vera)

Comment: I hadn't heard of this tools.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I like it very much. Is it different to [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) though? Astyle works pretty well for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks!  My understanding of astyle is that it changes tabs and spaces to make source files consistent, since different tools interpret tabs sometimes to be equivalent to 2, 4, or 6.  Since we parse the code and make a complete Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) we can do more than just modify the white space.  We can do many refactorings too.  Thanks again for the pointer to astyle.  I need to spend some time with it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the general wisdom is pick a style and go with it. It doesn't really matter too much what style you pick as long as you pick one. See python for a good example of the language enforcing a particular style and, while it irks some people, it works pretty well.

I guess the one's that people tend to care about are

- indenting, spaces vs tabs and number of spaces (or number of spaces the tabs represent)
- Where the brace goes
- spaces around operators `for(int i=0...` vs `for(int i = 0...`
- spaces after if before the (

Things I wouldn't be as interested in:

- Sorting the members of a class
- Enforcing variable naming schemes automagically (they should be in place but there are too many corner cases that cause trouble)
- Line length limits are a sore issue for me. Depending on what area of our code I will strictly use 80. But really, modern IDEs can deal with longer lines without too much trouble. But then printing becomes a pain. No matter what this is very hard to automate well. Again too many corner cases that cause trouble and would need to be tweaked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a style formatter.  e.g. format according to: gnu, bsd, k&r etc

e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: astyle and GNU indent are actually capable of that